# Android Studio is showing errors even if I didn't do any thing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android development and I have just created a new project with java. Even if I didn't do anything it's showing some weird errors

[image]

I don't know what to do now!!!

--Errors--

1. Cannot resolve symbol 'appcompact'
2. Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'
3. Method does not override method from its superclass
4. Cannot resolve method 'onCreate(android.os.Bundle)'
5. Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' in 'MainActivity'

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: This looks like the JDK isnt correctly configured in android studio. Make sure your JDK paths are correct!

Comment: Have you added appcompat dependency in app level build.gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Steps

**Build -> Clean Project**

**Build -> Rebuild Project**

**File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart**

If none of these above steps works then,

1. check whether you have configured Android **SDK** correctly. For this,

   **Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK tools**

   Check Android SDK Build Tool is Checked
2. Check you have configured SDK and JDK correctly

   **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location**

   There check you have SDK and JDK location

If SDK is not installed it will show option to download SDK there itself.